# Ultimo - 'Related products' owl Carousel

Tags: theme, products, related-products, slider

I am using Ultimo theme.

Does anybody know how to change the scrolling direction of the 'related products' slider? The slider is based on the popular Owl Carousel.

I would assume the code for this is inside: '[js/infortis/jquery/plugins/jquery.owlcarousel.min.js](http://switchlive.co.uk/js/infortis/jquery/plugins/jquery.owlcarousel.min.js)' but I am not 100% sure because I think it is a minified version of the original script which can be found on the [Owl Carousel developer's site](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js).

All I want to do is change the slider from scrolling horizontally to vertically if possible.

Any help would be most welcome, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Don't touch `jquery.owlcarousel.min.js,` 
The script for each slider is inline in the phtml file as example 
`list_featured_slider.phtml` you can find the script in line `242`.

`related_multi.phtml` line `110`

One more thing owlcarousel is not great with vertical scroll.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add animate.css

I haven't seen the ultimo theme but maybe you can find the owl js under skin\frontend\template_name\template_name\js folder and edit it like this. Hope this helps.

```
$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
  loop: true,
  autoplay: true,
  items: 1,
  nav: true,
  autoplayHoverPause: true,
  animateOut: 'slideOutUp',
  animateIn: 'slideInUp'
});
```